# PHP Error 500 Internal Server Error in Codeigniter 3 When large Transaction

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, webserver

I have a problem when execute large transaction in Codeigniter 3.

I create transaction for migrating old data like below:

```
// Controller
public function migrate_document_get()
{
    $this->benchmark->mark('code_start');

    $data = $this->Delivery_order_model->read_data_class_from_stock();

    foreach ($data as $obj) {
        $parameters = $this->Delivery_order_model->read_data_for_do($obj->class_no);
        $this->Delivery_order_model->create_data($parameters);
    }

    $this->benchmark->mark('code_end');

    $data['message'] = "Finish migrate document DO";
    $data['execution_time'] = round($this->benchmark->elapsed_time('code_start', 'code_end')) . " seconds";
    $this->response($data, REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
}

// Model
function create_data($data)
{
    $error = array();
    $affected_rows = 0;

    $this->mysql->trans_start();

    foreach ($data as $row) {
        $sql_insert_product = "";

        $class_no = $row['class_no'];
        $article_vendor = $row['article_vendor'];
        $style = $row['style'];
        $sku_promo = $row['sku_promo'];
        $retail = $row['retail'];
        $unique_id = $this->generate_unique_id($class_no, $article_vendor, $style, $sku_promo, $retail);
        $sku_no = $class_no . $unique_id . $style . $sku_promo . $retail;
        $article_no = $class_no . $style . $sku_promo . $retail;
        $res_field = $unique_id . $style . $sku_promo;

        $format = array();
        $format['dept_no'] = $row['dept_no'];
        $format['class_no'] = $class_no;
        $format['sku_no'] = $sku_no;

        if (!empty($row['ref_no'])) {
            $format['ref_no'] = $row['ref_no'];
        }

        $format['article_vendor'] = $article_vendor;
        $format['article_no'] = $article_no;
        $format['res_field'] = $res_field;
        $format['style'] = $style;
        $format['category_no'] = $row['category_no'];
        $format['size_no'] = $row['size_no'];
        $format['color_no'] = $row['color_no'];
        $format['material_no'] = $row['material_no'];
        $format['unique_id'] = $unique_id;
        $format['sku_promo'] = $sku_promo;

        if (!empty($row['exp_promo']) and $row['sku_promo'] != "00") {
            $format['exp_promo'] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', str_replace("'", "", $row['exp_promo']))));
        }

        $format['season_code'] = date('ym');
        $format['retail'] = $retail;
        $format['tag_type'] = $row['tag_type'];

        if (!empty($row['image'])) {
            $format['image'] = $row['image'];
        }

        $format['time_create'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        $sql_insert_product = $this->mysql->insert_ignore_string("msr_product", $format);

        // Transaction 1 -> INSERT msr_product
        $this->mysql->query($sql_insert_product);

        $sql_insert_do = "";
        $format_doc = "DO" . $class_no . date('Ymd');
        $do_id = $this->generate_do_id($format_doc);
        $doc_no = $format_doc . $do_id;
        $store_no = $row['store_no'];

        // INSERT msr_do
        $format_insert = array();
        $format_insert['do_no'] = $doc_no;
        $format_insert['store_no'] = $store_no;
        $format_insert['sku_no'] = $sku_no;
        $format_insert['do_date1'] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(date('Ymd')));
        $format_insert['do_date2'] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('60 day', strtotime(date('Ymd'))));
        $format_insert['do_status'] = 1;
        $format_insert['user_input'] = $row['nik'];
        $format_insert['ts_input'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $format_insert['status_item'] = 0;
        $format_insert['qty_store'] = $row['qty'];

        $format_update['qty_store'] = "qty_store + " . $row['qty'];

        $sql_insert_do = $this->mysql->insert_on_duplicate_update_string("msr_do", $format_insert, $format_update, true, false);

        // Transaction 2 -> INSERT msr_do
        $this->mysql->query($sql_insert_do);

        $affected_rows += $this->mysql->affected_rows();
    }

    $this->mysql->trans_complete();

    if ($this->mysql->trans_status() === FALSE) {
        $error = $this->mysql->error();
        $error['sql_product'] = $sql_insert_product;
        $error['sql_do'] = $sql_insert_do;
    }

    return $this->commonutil->format_output($affected_rows, $error);
}
```

When I execute method above in loop,
I facing an issue with error 500 internal server error.

but when I execute method like below one by one, not in the loop it's running normally.

```
// Controller
public function create_post()
{
    $this->benchmark->mark('code_start');

    $parameters = $this->post();

    if (!empty($parameters)) {
        $validate_param = $this->validate_parameter_create($parameters[0]);

        if ($validate_param->run() == TRUE) {
            $save = $this->Delivery_order_model->create_data($parameters);

            if (!empty($save) and $save['total_affected'] > 0) {
                $this->benchmark->mark('code_end');

                $output['status'] = REST_Controller::HTTP_OK;
                $output['error'] = false;
                $output['message'] = "Success create delivery order list.";
                $output['execution_time'] = $this->benchmark->elapsed_time('code_start', 'code_end') . " seconds.";
                $this->response($output, REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
            } else {
                $this->benchmark->mark('code_end');

                $output['status'] = REST_Controller::HTTP_NOT_MODIFIED;
                $output['error'] = true;
                $output['error_detail'] = $save['error'];
                $output['message'] = "Failed create delivery order list!";
                $output['execution_time'] = $this->benchmark->elapsed_time('code_start', 'code_end') . " seconds.";
                $this->response($output, REST_Controller::HTTP_NOT_MODIFIED);
            }
        } else {
            $this->benchmark->mark('code_end');

            $output['status'] = REST_Controller::HTTP_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY;
            $output['error'] = true;
            $output['error_detail'] = $validate_param->error_array();
            $output['message'] = "Required JSON Array! [{.....}]";
            $output['execution_time'] = $this->benchmark->elapsed_time('code_start', 'code_end') . " seconds.";
            $this->response($output, REST_Controller::HTTP_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY);
        }
    } else {
        $this->benchmark->mark('code_end');

        $output['status'] = REST_Controller::HTTP_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY;
        $output['error'] = true;
        $output['message'] = "Required parameters!";
        $output['execution_time'] = $this->benchmark->elapsed_time('code_start', 'code_end') . " seconds.";
        $this->response($output, REST_Controller::HTTP_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY);
    }
}

// Model
function create_data($data)
{
    $error = array();
    $affected_rows = 0;

    $this->mysql->trans_start();

    foreach ($data as $row) {
        $sql_insert_product = "";

        $class_no = $row['class_no'];
        $article_vendor = $row['article_vendor'];
        $style = $row['style'];
        $sku_promo = $row['sku_promo'];
        $retail = $row['retail'];
        $unique_id = $this->generate_unique_id($class_no, $article_vendor, $style, $sku_promo, $retail);
        $sku_no = $class_no . $unique_id . $style . $sku_promo . $retail;
        $article_no = $class_no . $style . $sku_promo . $retail;
        $res_field = $unique_id . $style . $sku_promo;

        $format = array();
        $format['dept_no'] = $row['dept_no'];
        $format['class_no'] = $class_no;
        $format['sku_no'] = $sku_no;

        if (!empty($row['ref_no'])) {
            $format['ref_no'] = $row['ref_no'];
        }

        $format['article_vendor'] = $article_vendor;
        $format['article_no'] = $article_no;
        $format['res_field'] = $res_field;
        $format['style'] = $style;
        $format['category_no'] = $row['category_no'];
        $format['size_no'] = $row['size_no'];
        $format['color_no'] = $row['color_no'];
        $format['material_no'] = $row['material_no'];
        $format['unique_id'] = $unique_id;
        $format['sku_promo'] = $sku_promo;

        if (!empty($row['exp_promo']) and $row['sku_promo'] != "00") {
            $format['exp_promo'] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', str_replace("'", "", $row['exp_promo']))));
        }

        $format['season_code'] = date('ym');
        $format['retail'] = $retail;
        $format['tag_type'] = $row['tag_type'];

        if (!empty($row['image'])) {
            $format['image'] = $row['image'];
        }

        $format['time_create'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        $sql_insert_product = $this->mysql->insert_ignore_string("msr_product", $format);

        // Transaction 1 -> INSERT msr_product
        $this->mysql->query($sql_insert_product);

        $sql_insert_do = "";
        $format_doc = "DO" . $class_no . date('Ymd');
        $do_id = $this->generate_do_id($format_doc);
        $doc_no = $format_doc . $do_id;
        $store_no = $row['store_no'];

        // INSERT msr_do
        $format_insert = array();
        $format_insert['do_no'] = $doc_no;
        $format_insert['store_no'] = $store_no;
        $format_insert['sku_no'] = $sku_no;
        $format_insert['do_date1'] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(date('Ymd')));
        $format_insert['do_date2'] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('60 day', strtotime(date('Ymd'))));
        $format_insert['do_status'] = 1;
        $format_insert['user_input'] = $row['nik'];
        $format_insert['ts_input'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $format_insert['status_item'] = 0;
        $format_insert['qty_store'] = $row['qty'];

        $format_update['qty_store'] = "qty_store + " . $row['qty'];

        $sql_insert_do = $this->mysql->insert_on_duplicate_update_string("msr_do", $format_insert, $format_update, true, false);

        // Transaction 2 -> INSERT msr_do
        $this->mysql->query($sql_insert_do);

        $affected_rows += $this->mysql->affected_rows();
    }

    $this->mysql->trans_complete();

    if ($this->mysql->trans_status() === FALSE) {
        $error = $this->mysql->error();
        $error['sql_product'] = $sql_insert_product;
        $error['sql_do'] = $sql_insert_do;
    }

    return $this->commonutil->format_output($affected_rows, $error);
}
```

I already resizing on DB temp space 
and I already check the method it's running normally

what's wrong with that, please give me some advice.

Comment: like below? why not show us exactly?

Comment: sorry I'm writing this issue in my phone, so i can't copy the code at this moment

Comment: The fact that this happens with a larger than normal transaction and not with a small one leads me think this is a backend server timing out. Normally you'd get a `504 Gateway Timeout` but depending on how your things are set up this may not be the case. You need to dig deeper. This may be the database failing under the transaction load, your php installation getting tired of waiting for the database to finish or even your application server (Apache, Nginx) timing out even though PHP and the database are still running. Try splitting the load into smaller chunks